# Matlab: Avoid exp(-3) conversion at text data input

Tags: matlab

I have a txt file with data, so I used the following function

```
M = dlmread('data.txt', '\t');
```

But My data is getting converted to exp(-3) how do I avoid that?

Here how the data look like:

```
M =

   1.0e+03 *

         0    0.0080    0.3500    0.1500    4.6990    0.0145    0.0740         0
         0    0.0080    0.4000    0.1700    4.7460    0.0120    0.0710         0
         0    0.0080    0.4000    0.1750    4.3850    0.0120    0.0720         0
         0    0.0060    0.2500    0.0720    3.1580    0.0195    0.0750         0
         0    0.0080    0.3040    0.1500    3.8920    0.0125    0.0720         0
         0    0.0080    0.3500    0.1450    4.4400    0.0140    0.0750         0
         0    0.0060    0.2500    0.1050    3.8970    0.0185    0.0750         0
         0    0.0060    0.1630    0.1330    3.4100    0.0158    0.0780    0.0010
         0    0.0080    0.2600    0.1100    4.0600    0.0190    0.0770         0
```

Comment: This is no conversion but only a display issue, i.e., "under the hood" all your precision is preserved. Use `format long` to display the data in higher precision.

Comment: @H.Muster what you have done is very discouraging. Look at the Title of the duplicate, how would someone new to Matlab would know that its the same. When You search on Matlab I didn't get the previously asked question as a recommendation. Putting a -1 point and then mark for deletion. Infact look at the answer below, the previous question doesn't really provide the answer what I was looking.

Comment: Please note that I answered your question in my comment. The fact that I marked the question as a possible duplicate is not meant as offense and should not discourage you; this is just the normal proceeding to keep the site clear. Furthermore, I did not down-vote (-1) your question; that was somebody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As H Muster says, this is a display issue.

A better way (in my opinion) of displaying your data is via num2str.

If you run

```
num2str(M)
```

you will see

```
ans =

0       0.008        0.35        0.15       4.699      0.0145       0.074           0
0       0.008         0.4        0.17       4.746       0.012       0.071           0
0       0.008         0.4       0.175       4.385       0.012       0.072           0
0       0.006        0.25       0.072       3.158      0.0195       0.075           0
0       0.008       0.304        0.15       3.892      0.0125       0.072           0
0       0.008        0.35       0.145        4.44       0.014       0.075           0
0       0.006        0.25       0.105       3.897      0.0185       0.075           0
0       0.006       0.163       0.133        3.41      0.0158       0.078       0.001
0       0.008        0.26        0.11        4.06       0.019       0.077           0
```

which is probably what you were expecting in the first place.

If you want more precision, pass a format string to num2str.

For example:

```
 num2str(M,'%8g')
```